# Why does the YouTube API queries rise so quick?

Tags: http, google-api, youtube

I recently (since a few months) have an issue regarding the number of requests sent by my javascript page to the YouTube's search list API. When I check Google's metrics page, it shows hundreds and even thousands of request per day, while i'm only doing a few.

On the image, you can see that the day before, my maximum limit was almost reached (10000), and today it's at about a few hundreds...

[image]

I thought at first that my script had a bug, sending 100 times more requests than it should... But when debugging, I found out that only 1 request was sent at a time. And even looking at a tcpdump using port 443 on TCP (and now UDP for QUIC's HTTP/3), it is far from 100 packets (only a few)...

So I thought it was an HTTP3 (new) issue, and fired up an old gnome browser, and tcpdump showed TCP flows, so it effectively uses HTTP/1.1 or /2, and got the same results ! Over a hundred queries seen on Google's service page.

I investigated even further, and even sending a single bash command with wget, I get the exact same results !! 102 queries more...

```
wget "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=h&type=video&videoDuration=any&fields=items(id(videoId)%2Csnippet(description%2Ct
itle))%2CnextPageToken%2CpageInfo%2CprevPageToken%2CregionCode&key=MYKEY..."
```

Anybody have an explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the word "queries" is a bit misleading in Google's webpage...

What is shown in the graph is actually the number of "tokens" used. And since 1 real search query equals to about 100 tokens, this is why the numbers rose so rapidly.